# How to batch SQL statements in Postgres using Golang

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

What is the fastest way to send batch requests to Postgres database using Golang? Each request contains 500-200000 rows.
Methods I know about are-
 1. Using database/sql package's transaction Begin, Prepare, Commit.
 2. Sending all data in one statement.
 3. Sending a list of statements using sql.Exec() method.
Is there some other way to send batch requests without making a connection at every statement? If not which is the best way of these?

This question is similar to question at- [Golang how do I batch sql statements with package database.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486436/golang-how-do-i-batch-sql-statements-with-package-database-sql)

Comment: Any question that begins with "What is the fastest way" is best answered by benchmarks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35388503/5315974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit old depesz [blog post](https://www.depesz.com/2007/07/05/how-to-insert-data-to-database-as-fast-as-possible/) on that. His programs are Perl scripts, but if you concentrate on SQL... Anyway - from DB perspective, you can use `COPY`, or `INSERT` with many rows in `VALUES`. It looks that around 20 is good choice, but it is worth to test that in your case. If performance is key factor, I would put around 2000-5000 rows per transaction. Also, from DB perspective transaction, and session are two separate things. So you can open session, and to many transactions in it.

For PostgreSQL starting new session per operation is really bad idea - DB spawns new process for each session. One of answers for the question you referred contains [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports). So you open connection, and then transaction, as it should be done.

Comment: In the blog post, `COPY` outperforms the `INSERT` with many rows. Is there any reason not to use `COPY` over `INSERT`?

Comment: not really. `pg_dump` generates dumps with `COPY` by default.